# Git update branch - from its base branch, not from master

Tags: git

I wonder if somebody can help me, or if this is answered already somewhere - I looked for that but could not find an answer, maybe my bad. :)

I created a git branch from another branch which is based on master.
The command was pretty much like
$ git checkout -b branch2 branch1

So, it is like:
master->branch1->branch2

There was plenty of work done in both branch1 and branch2 and those are close to be merged.
I would like to update branch2 from branch1 with the changes done in branch1 (not touching master) and then PR/merge them into master one by one.

How do I update branch2 to the current content of branch1 without losing new edits in branch2? Manual merging is fine, if needed. I tried "git pull" but that did not even try to update branch2 from branch1.

Thank you

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question. My answer below is probably incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```bash
git checkout branch1
git merge branch2
```

It will merge `branch2` into `branch1`

You can check the result with a GUI tool like `gitk`

Comment: dont forget to pull after checkout in case other parties were working on branch 1

Comment: @so-random-dude I think we misunderstood the question. I just read the question again carefully.